# Opening Code Blocks project file (.cbp) in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio, codeblocks

I'm switching over to Visual Studio 2008 from Code Blocks. I have a project written in Code Blocks, and I'd like to manage it in Visual Studio. The problem is that the project file for the program is in the .cbp file format. Is there any way to get this working in Visual Studio?

Comment: I'm running into the same issue. Did you ever figure this out? (I'm using VS 2010)